# sigma.js Включить Hover при 'mouseEnabled:false'

Tags: javascript, graph

Граф sigma.js. В нем мне не нужен зум, но нужен hover

Настраиваю его

```
settings: {
        autoRescale: false,
        mouseEnabled: false,
        touchEnabled: false,
        ...
}
```

Теперь хочу чтобы при наведении на `node` показывался `label`, как в обычном графе.

```
nodes: [
        {
            ...
            label: 'Node',
            ...
        }
    ],
```

Пытался добавить в настройки `enableHovering: true,` - не получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `settings` нужно заменить `mouseEnabled: false,` на `mouseWheelEnabled: false,`. Тогда зума не будет, а `hover` будет работать.